# Unable to declare two handlers for sqlstates

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

When running this:

```
   DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test BEFORE UPDATE ON test
     FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000';
      IF(older_record(NEW.last_action_timestamp, OLD.last_action_timestamp)) THEN
           SET @rowhash = (SELECT MD5(NEW));
           INSERT INTO test_db.test_table SELECT NEW.*, @rowhash;
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'old record'; 
      END IF 
      END
      $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following Error Message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
>        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000';
>        IF(older_record(NEW.l' at line 4

Answer (score 1):

A `DECLARE` statement must be followed by a "statement" -- see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html
Perhaps all you want is

```
BEGIN END;
```

Apparently an "empty statement" is not allowed?

Comment: I edit the question to implement your solution but i still get an error

Comment: Making another stab.